# Time series based on months since account opening rather than actual time

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is as follows with two tables

Table A (only one record for each account)

```
Account_id creation_date
0x66756    12-05-21
Ox77734    06-07-21
...        ...
```

Table B (multiple records for each account)

```
Account_id transaction_id transaction_value transaction_date
0x66756    AA344556       5.24              14-05-21
0x66756    AA556655       7.00              17-05-21
Ox77734    AA149876       9.66              08-07-21
0x66756    AA765900       1.63              25-06-21
Ox77734    AA433331       9.99              28-08-21
```

What I want is something to show this

```
account_id  count_of_transactions_month1_post_opening 
0x66756     2
Ox77734     1
```

Ideally then build so I can show a complete time series of how many transactions in every month post opening, but will be easier to start with this then iterate.

Comment: should the result not be 3 and 2?  and do you want the count 0 for no transactions at all

Comment: @nbk there are 3 transactions in total but only 2 are within the first month of account opening for 0x66756 - same logic applies for the other account.

Yes,  I would like count for no transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` and a ON condition with the date, give you the correct count.

This will select the same month

```
SELECT A.[Account_id], COUNT( B.[Account_id]) as count_of_transactions_same_month_post_opening 
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B  ON A.[Account_id] = B.[Account_id]
AND FORMAT([transaction_date],'YYYY-MM') 
= FORMAT([creation_date],'YYYY-MM')
GROUP BY A.[Account_id]
```

Another faster approach for this mentioned by John Cappelletti.

```
SELECT A.[Account_id], COUNT( B.[Account_id]) as count_of_transactions_same_month_post_opening 
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B  ON A.[Account_id] = B.[Account_id]
AND  convert(varchar(7),[transaction_date],120) 
= convert(varchar(7),[creation_date],120) 
GROUP BY A.[Account_id]
```

This will select exact one month after created date from tableA.

```
SELECT A.[Account_id], COUNT( B.[Account_id]) as count_of_transactions_month1_post_opening 
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B  ON A.[Account_id] = B.[Account_id]
AND [transaction_date]
BETWEEN  [creation_date] AND DATEADD(month, 1,[creation_date])
GROUP BY A.[Account_id]
```

The result would be in both cases (I added an account for 0).

[image: resultset]

Comment: Two items:  1) Kudos for typing that ridiculous column name.   2) As much as I love the functionality of format(), I tend to use it sparingly, i.e. variables and final results.   convert(varchar(7),D,120) is more than 10 times faster than format().   Just for fun take a peek at  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c405bc4ad5a205b6f9867df7d4e6a9cf    Either way +1

Answer (score -1):

You can use tableB only and aggregate on account_id and month,
Extract month from the transaction date field and use it in the group by clause.
I assume that account is able to transact only when it is active
Else you can join with TableA on account id and the  filter on transaction date>= create date

In final select you can keep only the required columns.